# Insert string inside the head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 var c = <head></head><body></body>
```

i want to insert base tag between head tag. The above head tag is not in html form its inside the variable, now i want to modify this c variable like shown below

```
<head><base target="_blank"/></head><body></body>
```

Anyone knows.....

Comment: Is your `c` variable supposed to be a javascript string like `var c = "<head></head><body></body>"` and you want to modify the string?

Comment: Since it looks like you're relatively new to StackOverflow, it generally works better if you hang around immediately after posting your question to see if there are followup questions for people to correctly understand what you are asking.  If not, then people may go off in the wrong direction or you may miss the largest set of people who will see your question because when they see it, they are confused as to what you mean.  As it is now, you have answers for two completely different interpretations of what your question might mean because it wasn't completely clear what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you proposed isn't valid javascript or HTML, I'm assuming what you really meant was that you have a javascript variable `c` that is a javascript string like this:

```
var c = '<head></head><body></body>';
```

and you want to change it to this:

```
var c = '<head><base target="_blank"/></head><body></body>';
```

If that is what you meant, you could do that like this:

```
c = c.replace('<head>', '<head><base target="_blank"/>');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4p6wf/

---

If you meant something different, then please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: @Hello Jfriend. Yes iam new to stackoverflow, Your solution works thanks for your help,i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.append()`:

```
$('head').append('<base target="_blank"/>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxWm3/2/)**

to append at first position,use `.prepend()`:

```
$('head').prepend('<base target="_blank"/>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxWm3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method:

```
var c = '<head></head><body></body>';
$('<base target="_blank"/>').appendTo('head');
```

Comment: This will append it to any `<head>` tags in the document, not inside the variable.